# How to popup html page from wicket page?

Tags: java, wicket

I am trying to popup a html page from wicket application. The html page will not have corresponding .java file. The page is static html page.

I tried to pop up html page which is a part of wicket application using following logic:

```
PopupSettings popupSettings = 
            new PopupSettings(PopupSettings.RESIZABLE | PopupSettings.SCROLLBARS).setHeight(500).setWidth(700);


Link link = new Link("link") { 
      @Override 
      public void onClick() { 
            System.out.println("clicked"); 
            setResponsePage(PopupPage.class); 
       } 
       }; 

link.setPopupSettings(popupSettings); 
add(link);
```

But for this to work i need to have html page with its java page. But in my requirement I have fixed html page (say test.html) and I want to pop up it.
Also I want to popup this html page on click of button. But I didn't get any method like setPopupSettings() for button. Can someone tell me the way in which I can implement it for a button?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way i can think of is to add button in your html:

```
<button type="button" wicket:id="popupButton">Pop</button>
```

And in the code you can do something like this:

```
add(new WebMarkupContainer("popupButton").add(AttributeAppender.append("onclick",
    "window.open('test.html', 'popup', 'width=500,height=700,scrollbars=yes');")));
```

Or if you want it to be more dynamic, you can use a model:

```
add(new WebMarkupContainer("popupButton").add(AttributeAppender.append("onclick",
        new AbstractReadOnlyModel<String>() {
            @Override
            public String getObject() {
                return "window.open('test.html', 'popup', 'width=500,height=700,scrollbars=yes');";
            }
        })));
```